# I want to get the green pixel component (0-255) from this info:

Tags: android

Two statements:

```
paint.setColor(Color.rgb(0xFF, valColor, 0));
canvas.drawPoint(x, y, paint);
```

establish actual pixel color on something I'm looking at.

If I subsequently Log.i INFO on the what `paint.getColor()` returns for any given pixel I see values that are anywhere from "255" to "62976" (and maybe higher).

How do I get the green component (0-255) exclusively for the pixel I'm working on?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Colors are 32 bit numbers.  The first byte is the alpha channel, then the red channel, green channel, and blue channel.  SO you can mask it off:

`color && 0xff000000 >> 24;`  will get you the alpha.
`color && 0x00ff0000 >> 16;`  will get you the red.
`color && 0x0000ff00 >> 8;`  will get you the green.
`color && 0x000000ff;`  will get you the blue.